# Dimensions of cycles and boundaries in a full simplex

Tags: combinatorics, homology-cohomology, combinatorial-geometry, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

$\newcommand\rk{\operatorname{rk}}$Let $\Delta_n$ denote the full $n$-simplex $\{n,\dotsc,0\}$.  It is clear that there are $\binom{n+1}{d+1}$ many $d$-simplices, since a $d$-simplex corresponds to a subset of $\Delta_n$ of $d+1$ elements.  This means that the cochains $C_d(\Delta_n)$ are free of rank $\binom{n+1}{d+1}$.

I would like to know the ranks of the cycles $Z_d(\Delta_n)$ and the boundaries $B_d(\Delta_n)$.  Certainly we have $\rk C_d(\Delta_n) = \rk B_{d-1}(\Delta_n) + \rk Z_d(\Delta_n)$, and since $\Delta_n$ is contractible, we get $\rk Z_{d}(\Delta_n) = \rk B_d(\Delta_n)$.

I have read that $\rk Z_d(\Delta_n) = \binom{n}{d+1}$; the above formula then reflects the recursion formula for binomial coefficients.  However, I struggle to see how the rank of $\rk Z_d(\Delta_n)$ is obtained.

Comment: Typo in your first line: change $\binom{n}{d+1}$ to $\binom{n+1}{d+1}$. Correspondingly, the formula for the rank of $Z_n$ should have $n$ in the top, not $n-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the correct equation is $\text{rk } Z_d(\Delta^n)=\binom{n}{d+1}$.

Well, using the two equations you gave, you can prove that $\text{rk } Z_d(\Delta^n)=\binom{n}{d+1}$ by induction on $d$. For simplicity, let $z_d=\text{rk }Z_d(\Delta^n)$, and $b_d=\text{rk } B_d(\Delta^n)$.
\begin{align}
z_d
&=\binom{n+1}{d+1}-b_{d-1}\tag{rank-nullity}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{d+1}-z_{d-1}\tag{contractible}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{d+1}-\binom{n}{d}\tag{induction hypothesis}\\
&=\binom{n}{d+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks; sometimes, seeing induction is hard even if it hits you in the face.